# List Of Multithreading throwing exception

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I currently have a thread which at a stage goes through a List(of CustomClass) constantly with a ForEach loop. My problem is if I try to modify that list from the UI thread it throws a:

```
Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute
```

I tried using SyncLock which clearly doesn't work the way I thought, I also tried this:

```
Dim TempList As System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of CustomClass) = G_.ActiveEnts.AsReadOnly
For each _Element in TempList
   'Do stuff
Next
```

And other variations of it, like converting to an array

Comment: the error message sounds more like it is related to how you are modifying it rather than thread related - you cant remove items from inside a FOR/EACH loop or you get that error

Comment: I wasn't modifying it in the loop, just reading it. I was modifying the list in the UI thread. I fixed it anyway and posted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course after about 5 seconds of writing this question I decided to put a SyncLock on every access to the List of, rather than just in the thread. So whenever I modify the List of it SyncLocks it and this fixed it.